# VS2012 changes IIS Express site bindings, how do I stop it?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express, applicationhost

I have several sites running in IIS Express for the same project.

They are mapped to real domains via the host file, `local.xxx.com` etc. instead of `localhost:XXX`

I add a binding for `https`, under one site in the `applicationhost.config` file , but it is constantly removed, seemingly randomly by VS2012.  Meaning, I add it. save it, and it works, then at some point in time later, VS2012 edits my `applicationhost.config` file and removes, just the `https` binding, leaving the `http` binding intact.  It doesn't do this on all sites in the config, even if those sites are in the same solution.  Just one site.

How do I make it stop?